# Anime movie where at the end a guy turns into a giant frog deity

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I don't remember much of the actual movie, but I do remember the main character being a girl, and the ending scene of the movie taking place amidst clouds.

A guy she trusted turned out to actually be evil (?) and transformed into a giant frog deity (I believe they then fought). I remember the transformation scene because it freaked me out as a kid.

I don't think the release date exceeded 2010, since I watched it around that time.

Comment: Are you sure that the main character is a girl, and the giant frog deity a boy? With reversed genders, your description would match "Brave Story" (see [entry in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_Story)): Several scenes, in particular near the end, happen amidst clouds; a girl that gave the MC helpful hints as a disembodied voice turns up in person and turns into a frog after the MC rejects her request to kill the goddess of fate.  The anime was released 2006, decidedly before 2010.

Comment: Thank you so much straycat! (I wanted to comment directly under you but apparently you need a set amount of reputation for that oop) I did have the genders mixed, cant even trust your memory these days. Man this movie freaked me out as a kid, can't wait to watch it again ^v^